# Fragments and the backStack show/hide

Tags: android, android-fragments

First of all thankyou for looking at this.
I have 4 Fragments. One is a Menu Fragment that displays the menu. I have 2 List Fragments that display a list of data and pictures. the 4th fragment is a details fragment.
Everything starts out normal.

Setup:

I click a list button it shows up and the menu frag is hidden behind it.

I click on an entry in the list fragment it uses an interface to pass data and show the details fragment.

I click the back button once it takes me to the list fragment like it should.

I click the back button again and it shows the menu frag like it should.

Problem:

If i click on a list button again the list shows up but the menu fragment is still showing behind it.

I am assuming that it has something to do with the backstack and maybe i am not using it correctly. Any help is greatly appreciated. If someone could explain this issue that would be amazing. If you would like me to post any part of my conde just let me know but i feel like my issue is with the backstack and this is the part of my code that i mess with the backstack.

```
private Fragment visible;
private Fragment mVisibleCached;
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();
    visible = mVisibleCached;

}
```

.
.

```
public void showFragment(int fragIn) {
    final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
    final FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
    ft.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in, android.R.anim.fade_out);
    if (visible != null) {
        ft.hide(visible);
        //ft.remove(visible);
        mVisibleCached = visible;
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

    }
    switch (fragIn) {
    case 0:
        menuFrag = ((MenuFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag(MenuFragment.TAG));
        if (menuFrag == null) {
            menuFrag = MenuFragment.newInstance();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, menuFrag, MenuFragment.TAG);
        } else {
            // ft.show(menuFrag);
            //ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, menuFrag, MenuFragment.TAG);
            if (!menuFrag.isVisible()) {
                ft.show(menuFrag);
            }
        }

        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        visible = menuFrag;
        break;
    case 1:
        programsFrag = ((ListFrag) fm.findFragmentByTag(PROGRAMS_TAG));
        if (programsFrag == null) {
            programsFrag = ListFrag.newInstance(false);
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, programsFrag, PROGRAMS_TAG);
        } else {
            // ft.show(programsFrag);
            //ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, programsFrag, PROGRAMS_TAG);

            // ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, programsFrag);
            if (!programsFrag.isVisible()) {
                ft.show(programsFrag);
            }
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        visible = programsFrag;
        break;
    case 2:
        hostsFrag = ((ListFrag) fm.findFragmentByTag(HOSTS_TAG));
        if (hostsFrag == null) {
            hostsFrag = ListFrag.newInstance(true);
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, hostsFrag, HOSTS_TAG);
        } else {
            // ft.show(hostsFrag);
            //ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, hostsFrag, HOSTS_TAG);

            // ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, hostsFrag);
            if (!hostsFrag.isVisible()) {
                ft.show(hostsFrag);
            }
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        visible = hostsFrag;
        break;
    case 3:
        detailsFrag = ((DetailsFrag) fm.findFragmentByTag(DetailsFrag.TAG));
        if (detailsFrag == null) {
            detailsFrag = DetailsFrag.newInstance();
            ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFrag, DetailsFrag.TAG);
        } else {
            //ft.add(R.id.fragment_container, detailsFrag, DetailsFrag.TAG);
            if (!detailsFrag.isVisible()) {
                ft.show(detailsFrag);
            }
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        visible = detailsFrag;
        break;
    }
    ft.commit();
}
```

Comment: Try using ft.replace instead of ft.add

Comment: That actually works but i also found my problem. I added in a bunch of log messages to tell me what was going on with the visible and mCached fragments. Turns out after pressing back twice from the details fragment both visible and mcached were list fragments and visible was set to a list fragment. To fix it without using replace i can setup a connection from the listFragment to the Fragment activity that sets mCached to the menuFragment which is always next on the backstack. I will post solution when i get it working. But Thankyou @rascuache i forgot about replace.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue by following your method, it is not elegant but it works for me..

Instead of your 2 fragments I used an integer var and an arraylist of integer (the integer are ids of fragments)

`int visible;`

```
ArrayList<Integer> cachedVisible= new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Then in the method showing the right fragment i did something like this

```
private void setVisibleFragment(int id) {
if(visible!=0){
        cachedVisible.add(visible);
    }else{
        cachedVisible.add(R.id.home);
    }


   switch (id) {
        case R.id.settings:
        visible=R.id.settings;
        break;
    case R.id.services:
        ft.hide(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.settings_frag));
        ft.hide(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.plugin_frag));
        ft.show(fm.findFragmentById(R.id.service_frag));
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commitAllowingStateLoss();
        visible=R.id.services;
        break;
        ....
   }
}
```

And at the end in the FragmentActivity

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(cachedVisible.size()==0){
        finish();
    }else{
    visible = cachedVisible.get(cachedVisible.size()-1);
    cachedVisible.remove(cachedVisible.size()-1);
     }
    setVisibleFragment(visible);
    cachedVisible.remove(cachedVisible.size()-1);   
}
```

Hope it can help someone ;)

Comment: I ended up doing approximately the same thing